# Swift2.0 Multipeer Connectivity Cannot Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, multipeer-connectivity

I have a question I made a little Multipeer Connectivity app
by [a tutorial](http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/09/multipeer-connectivity-on-ios-8-with-swift.html) I rewrite the code a little bit so it works with swift 2.0 .
Everything works fine but if I send my simulation an invite from my iPhone 6s it dose not connect why ?

Code:

```
import MultipeerConnectivity
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate {

var browser : MCBrowserViewController!
var assistant : MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var session : MCSession!
var peerID: MCPeerID!

@IBOutlet var chatView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet var messageField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    print( UIDevice.currentDevice().name )
    //self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .Required)
    self.session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID)
    self.session.delegate = self

    // create the browser viewcontroller with a unique service name
    self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "LCOC-Chat", session: self.session)
    self.browser.delegate = self

    // tell the assistant to start advertising our fabulous chat
    self.assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:"LCOC-Chat", discoveryInfo:nil, session:self.session)
    self.assistant.start()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func showBrowser(sender: UIButton) {
    self.presentViewController(self.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func sendChat(sender: UIButton) {
    if self.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        if let msg = self.messageField.text!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
            // 3
            do {
                try self.session.sendData(msg, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Unreliable)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    //-----------------this might ne3ed to be UNCOMMENTED!!!
    //self.updateChat(self.messageField.text!, fromPeer: self.peerID)
    self.messageField.text = ""
}

func updateChat(text : String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    // Appends some text to the chat view
    print("Incoming msg: \(text)")
    // If this peer ID is the local device's peer ID, then show the name
    // as "Me"
    var name : String
    switch peerID {
    case self.peerID:
        name = "Me"
    default:
        name = peerID.displayName
    }
    // Add the name to the message and display it
    let message = "\(name): \(text)\n"
    self.chatView.text = self.chatView.text + message
}

func browserViewControllerDidFinish(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func browserViewController(browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController, shouldPresentNearbyPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}
//---------------------------------------Session
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    // Called when a peer sends an NSData to us

    // This needs to run on the main queue
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        print("Incoming data:::")
        //let msg = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let msg = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        self.updateChat(msg, fromPeer: peerID)
    }
}
func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.Connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.Connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")

    case MCSessionState.NotConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}
// The following methods do nothing, but the MCSessionDelegate protocol
// requires that we implement them.
func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) {
}
func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) {

}
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multipeer connectivity test on iphone and a simulator simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594714/multipeer-connectivity-test-on-iphone-and-a-simulator-simultaneously)

Answer (score 0):

multiplier can connect via ***bluetooth/wifi***. If you have **same wifi** network both device (iPhone and simulator). it can be connected.

But if you have **not wifi** in both devices. multiplier will try make a connection by **bluetooth.** As simulator does **not support bluetooth**,so multiplier connectivity can be **failed** by this situation

Answer (score 0):

Let me re-word Jamil's response slightly...  If the iPhone has bluetooth turned on, it will use bluetooth rather than WiFi.  Since the simulator doesn't support bluetooth, the connection will not be made.  Try connecting with bluetooth turned off.